# jQuery/JWPlayer: Will not work while playing MP4 video from S3 in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jwplayer

Here is my markup for the video in the markup:

```
  <div class="jw-wrapper" data-url="//amazon.url.here" data-thumbnail="<%= asset_path("marketing-video-placeholder.jpg") %>" data-width="770" data-height="443" style="">
    <div id="jwplayer-video">Loading the player...</div>
  </div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
    if $(".jw-wrapper").length > 0
      initializeJWPlayer($(".jw-wrapper[data-url]"))

initializeJWPlayer = (elements) ->
  $.each elements, (i, element) ->
    element = $(element)
    _file = element.attr("data-url")
    _image = element.attr("data-thumbnail")
    _width = element.attr("data-width")
    _height = element.attr("data-height")

    child_index = 0
    child_index++  while element[0].childNodes[child_index].childNodes.length is 0
    name = $(element[0].childNodes[child_index]).attr("id")
    jwplayer(name).setup
      file: "https:#{_file}"
      height: parseInt(_height)
      image: _image
      width: parseInt(_width)
      startparam: "starttime"
      type: "mp4"
      abouttext: "RecruitTalk"
      aboutlink: "https://www.recruittalk.com"
      html5player: "<%= asset_path('jwplayer.html5.js') %>"
      logo: 
        file: "<%= asset_path('rt-logo-icon.png') %>"
        link: "https://www.recruittalk.com"
```

Everything works perfectly in FF, Chrome and Safari, but will not work in IE. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: After a quick google : POSSIBLE DUPLICATE : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187382/jw-player-not-playing-mp4-video-format-videos-in-ie9-and-ie10

Comment: Fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jw+player+not+playing+mp4+ie  AND  http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player

Comment: Also, where is this running?

Comment: https://www.recruittalk.com/pages/showcase_for_athletes

Comment: I changed the mimetype on S3 to be video/mp4 and still nothing is working :(

Comment: This plays in IE for me.

Comment: It does? ugh... I am using browserstack.com to test with

Comment: Got everything working in IE... must have been some cache issue... thanks!

Comment: Yeah, works for IE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to this page and 'troubleshoot' your situation by yourself:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28840/troubleshooting-your-setup

Also, [how about your `<doctype>`](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player)?

> Note two very common issues prevent smooth playback of videos in
>   Internet Explorer 9/10. First, you need to set  to
>   prevent triggering IE's quirks mode. Second, your videos must be
>   served with the video/mp4 mimetype or IE will refuse to play them. See
>   our troubleshooting guide for more common issues.

Comment: I changed all of my videos on S3 to have the video/mp4 mimetype, but am still having the same error